# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement the twilio_voice: ^0.0.9 plug in and register my firebase app at the same time but, when I run my registration function I get the error:

```
E/flutter (27321): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND
E/flutter (27321):
E/flutter (27321): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:607
E/flutter (27321): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:156
E/flutter (27321): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27321): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call
package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23
E/flutter (27321): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27321): #3      HttpsCallable.call
package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:35
E/flutter (27321): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27321): #4      _TextScreenState.register
package:buddiesDrivers/CallScreen/TextScreen.dart:72
E/flutter (27321): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27321):
E/flutter (27321): #0      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call
package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:39
E/flutter (27321): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27321): #1      HttpsCallable.call
package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:35
E/flutter (27321): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I am have firebase implemented and running and I am getting my token when logging in. The app seems to fail when calling the httpsCallable("voice-accessToken") in the app. Here is the function:

```
  register() async {
    print("voip-registtering with token ");
    print("voip-calling voice-accessToken");

    final function =
        FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("voice-accessToken");

    final data = {
      "platform": Platform.isIOS ? "iOS" : "Android",
    };

    final result = await function.call(data);
    print("voip-result");
    print(result.data);
    String androidToken;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      androidToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      print("androidToken is " + androidToken);
    }
    TwilioVoice.instance
        .setTokens(accessToken: result.data, deviceToken: androidToken);
  }
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: Have you followed [twilio_voice: ^0.0.9](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_voice/example)?. If yes, have you added cloud functions in import?

Comment: Have you get any solution?

Comment: Still no. I am working to get assistance on this now.